# Painting on image doesn't show instantly on the object

Tags: texturing, image

I'm having a issue in the Texture Paint Mode and I can't find what's wrong.

Here is my problem : When I paint on the "Image editor" windows it doesn't instantly show the stroke on my object in the 3D viewport, sometimes I can see the beginning of the stroke but it disappears almost instantly too.
So I have to wait the end of the stroke to see what I did and it's very frustating.

I have to precise that this is happening since I update to 2.83, never had this problem in 2.82.

I need your help guys, thanks in advance.

EDIT : After further analysis, it only happens in Solid Render viewport

Answer (score 0):

That is by design: Solid render mode will not display textures.

Textures will only be visible in Material Preview or Render Preview mode